# Postgres Minor Version Upgrade from 11.4 to 11.7

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-11

I want to upgrade the PostgreSQL version from 11.4 to 11.7. What are the steps involved?

Comment: On CentOS: `yum upgrade postgresql-11`

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) advises:

> Minor releases never change the internal storage format and are always compatible with earlier and later minor releases of the same major version number. For example, version 10.1 is compatible with version 10.0 and version 10.6. Similarly, for example, 9.5.3 is compatible with 9.5.0, 9.5.1, and 9.5.6. To update between compatible versions, you simply replace the executables while the server is down and restart the server. The data directory remains unchanged — minor upgrades are that simple.

In addition, you should check the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11-7.html) for additional requirements.
In your case, additional activities are necessary if you are using the `intarray` contrib module.